# Z-indexing a SVG Element

Tags: html, css, svg

Hi I am havng an issue with setting the Z-index of a SVG element with respect to an HTML Element

My HTML Element(Popup) has a z-index of 4 My SVG Element(Line) has z-index of 3

But still my SVG element is overlapping the html popup. If i reduce the z-index on svg further it disappears like in the below screenshots

SVG z-index @ 3

[image]

SVG Z index @ 2

[image]

Is there anyway I can setup the z-index so that the line is drawn behind the popup?

Thank You

EDIT:

heres what I have tried till now

The popover consists of 4 divs

```css
.markerBubble {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius : 4px;
  box-shadow:4px 6px #888888;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height:150px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  z-index: 4;
}

.markerBubbleouter{
  display: flex;
  
}
 .markerBubble1{
  width:60%;
  padding-right:10px;
  text-align:right;
 }
 .markerBubble2{
  width:30%;
  text-align:left;
 }
```

markerBubble contains the rest of 3 divs outer,1 and 2 so I have put z-index on markerBubble.

For the SVG Line i have put the following CSS

```css
.leader-line{
  position: relative;
z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: `z-index` will only work on an element whose `position` property has been explicitly set to` absolute`, `fixed`, or `relative`. Did you set it?

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara Yes, Both the elements have absolute position

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara Hi I have edited the post with code

Comment: http://output.jsbin.com/rulowifafi

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara In my case I want the SVG element to be behind HTML element. When i set the z-index of svg lower it disapprears

Comment: just make the div elements z-index to top of the svg like this in the link below, http://output.jsbin.com/guxobeyiyu

Comment: Please paste the html and css code, Will try to do it

Comment: This is very nice explained in this pen: [SVG z-index - a pen by Blake Bowen](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/YXoEQe)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].